# Disable LightBox HTTP Requests

Tags: lightbox2

I'm trying to maintain a website that was built with the jquery lightbox plugin. When a user loads one of the pages which uses lightbox, the server logs indicate that lightbox is making a second http request. The sequence of events in the logs looks like this:

1. The user requests example.com/subfolder/data/myPage.jsp
2. When lightbox loads, it initiates a http request to example.com/subfolder/data
3. Since there isn't anything meaningful in example.com/subfolder/data (it's just the parent folder for the jsp), it just throws some errors in the log about page not found. These errors are filling up lots of errors on the server and my goal is to make lightbox stop initiating these requests.

Does anyone have any suggestions about what lightbox config I might have misconfigured to cause these http requests? When I look at the jsp page, the only things that I see is the line which loads the lightbox javascript library and an attribute data-lightbox="image-1" on one of the html tags.